# How to restore a single table from a .sql postgresql backup?

Tags: postgresql, sed, postgresql-9.1

A table's rows were mistakenly deleted from the database. We have a db backup which results in a sql file that can restored like so:

```
psql -h localhost -d proddump -f /Users/U/Desktop/prod_db_backup/PostgreSQL/site_prod.sql
```

This ends up doing a full restore locally. But what we need is to restore a single table's rows to production. Any tips on how to make this work with PostgreSQL 9.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't do SQL backups if you need single table restore, etc. [Use `pg_dump`'s `-Fc` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) - the "custom" format. This can be restored using `pg_restore`. Selective restore is possible, as are all sorts of other handy features. `pg_restore` can convert a custom-format dump into an SQL dump later if you need it.

If you're stuck with an existing dump, your only options are:

- Use a text editor to extract the target table data to a separate file and just restore that; or
- Restore the dump to a throwaway database then use `pg_dump` to take a selective dump including just that table. Since it's throwaway, you can use a separate Pg instance on some unloaded fast-but-unsafe machine where you turn on all the "make it fast but eat my data if you like" options like `fsync=off`. You should *NEVER* set that in production.

Comment: Is it possible to create `pg_dumpall` backup in `-Fc` format?

Comment: @vyegorov, pg_dumpall doesn't have -F flag -- It can dump database in SQL format only.

Answer (score 27):

I'm not aware of any tool for this, but this one-liner extracts `precious_table` from `my_backup.sql` file:

```
sed -n '/^COPY precious_table /,/^\\\.$/p' my_backup.sql
```

Comment: My precious... table.

Comment: This is the answer because if you have this question, you already have .sql dump and probably don't have data to re-do the dump in recommended format. Sure, for future use one should do `pg_dump -Fc` but this wonderful `sed` one-liner does the job as asked.

Comment: Where does this precious_table get extracted to and how do I use that to restore that single table?

Comment: @vepzfe to standard output. Then just pipe the output to `psql` (or redirect to a new .sql file)

Answer (score 13):

There is an easy way.

'pg_restore' has a '--table/-t' option.

```
pg_restore -a -t your_table /path/to/dump.sql
```

Use '-h' for remote host.
See other options [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: Right, sorry, file should be made by `pg_dump` first

Answer (score 9):

You can use grep + sed in roder to get table data:

First, you need to identify boundaries:

```
$ fgrep -Ehn '^(COPY |CREATE TABLE )' db.sql
49:CREATE TABLE test (
60:CREATE TABLE test2 (
71:CREATE TABLE test3 (
82:COPY test (i) FROM stdin;
100090:COPY test2 (i) FROM stdin;
200098:COPY test3 (i) FROM stdin;
```

In order to extract data for table test2:

```
sed -n '100090,200097p' < db.sql | sed -e 's/^COPY test2/COPY new_table_name/' > new_table_name.sql
```

Note, you need to subtract one from the second number (i.e exclude next copy stmt)

Now, you can load `new_table_name.sql` and restore data which you need. 
Now, you can load data into new table

Comment: command now to work is just "grep" instead "fgrep"

Answer (score 4):

I've recently written a step by step guide on how to [restore individual postgres tables](https://thomasvilhena.com/2020/11/restoring-individual-postgres-table).

In short it doesn't work with SQL backups, you need to switch to `pg_dump` to generate backup files:

```sh
pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --schema "public" --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "my_database.dump" "my_database"
```

Then, whenever you need to restore a specific table for data recovery or bug investigating purposes, you'll have to:

1. Create an empty local database `my_database_restored`
2. Create the table that needs to be restored `my_table` in the empty database
3. Run `pg_restore` to selectively import desired table’s data:

```sh
pg_restore.exe -U postgres --data-only -d "my_database_restored" -t "my_table" "my_database.dump"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've write some commands to restore only the data for one table, from a plain text pg_dumpall. Inspired from Zouppen, thanks.

Restore the data of a table from a backup plain text SQL, done for example with pg_dumpall.

1. go to the directory `/data/bkp/` where the backup is (`pg_full_bak.dmp`)

```
cd /data/bkp/
ls -l
```

2. extract the data from table `my_table` from schema `public` into the file `my_table.sql`

```
sed -n '/^COPY public.my__table /,/^\\\.$/p' pg_full_bak.dmp > my_table.sql
ls -l
```

3. check that the data is correct

```
less my_table.sql
```

4. connect to the database `db_name` containing the empty table `my_table` which we want to restore, with an account that has write permission on the table

```
psql -d db_name
```

5. check that my_table is empty

```
select count(*) nb from my_table ;
+------+
|  nb  |
+------+
|   0  |
+------+
```

6. import the data

```
\i my_table.sql
```

7. check that it worked correctly

```
select count(*) nb from my_table;
+-------+
|   nb  |
+-------+
| 9876  |
+-------+
```

That's working for me under pg **9.3**

**The easy way : steps 2, 4 & 6**

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have [`pg_dumpall`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pg-dumpall.html) dump around. And I would like to restore table named `users` from the database named `edc`, as you most likely *will* have equally named tables in different databases and even schemas.

For my case, the following `sed` oneliner works:

```sh
sed -ne '/^\\connect edc/,/^\\connect/{/\susers\(\s\|$\)/,/;\|\\\./p}' pg92.dump
```

What it does:

1. `/^\\connect edc/,/^\\connect/` limits the search to be the scope of my database;
2. `{…}` will perform all inside commands for the range;
3. `/\susers\(\s\|$\)/` matches all lines with `users` on it's own, including at the end of the line;
4. `/;\|\\\./` matches lines with `;` or containing `\.`
5. `p` forces the matching lines to be outputted (note, that sed is invoked with `-n`).

Depending on the complexity of your data, you might need to tweak this.

All you have to do is to pipe `sed` output to the `psql` command with right switches.