# restore single table dump from a sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql, dump, psql

I have full dump of sql file like `dump_full.sql` of size `1.3GB`

And it has some tables like

```
dancing_core_spice
dancing_sea_beast

forde_clear_one
forde_super_now
```

Now what i want is need to restore/fetch/dump `only data` of these tables from `dump_full.sql`file

```
psql -U postgres --table=dancing_core_spice dump_full.sql > dancing_core_spice.sql
```

i tried the above command but it is not working

So can anyone please let me know how to take the dump of only single table from the sql file(full dump)

Answer (score 2):

For these type of operations the dump file should be in the postgresql custom format created with [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html):

```
pg_dump -Fc
```

Then you can restore a single table with [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html)

```
pg_restore --table=dancing_core_spice dump_full.sql > dancing_core_spice.sql
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826862/how-to-restore-a-single-table-from-a-sql-postgresql-backup) provides tips to handle your actual case:

- Extract the sql code from the file. With an editor, a script or whatever
- Restore the dump to temp database and dump it again with pg_dump

Comment: You can't use pg_restore with a SQL file as the input.

Comment: It is giving me `pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

Comment: We can restore the dropped table from a script in three step process.   First extract the table structure from the sql dump , secondly extract the data from the sql file.  Third step is to run the sql's  in order to create table and restore .  a) sed -n '/CREATE TABLE tblname/,/);/p' /tmp/dump.sql >/tmp/ct.sql  b)sed -n '/COPY tblnamel/,/\\./p' /tmp/dump.sql  > /tmp/cv.sql  c)psql -U postgres <db name>
>\i /tmp/ct.sql
>\i /tmp/cv.sql
>\q

Comment: Thanks for the tip sramay. Feel free to open a new answer. But take into account that sometimes instead of COPY the dump is done with INSERT statements or even one INSERT per row statement